# Working with UTC and current time zone

Tags: angularjs, postgresql, python-2.7, datetime, momentjs

I'm working on a project that was used only in one country but now is in using in several countries.

So I'm working in some DateTime issues, as you can image.

I'm using angular js for my frontend, python for my backend and Postgres as my database in this project.

To avoid any problem with DateTime and try to make more easy to work with the timezones I'm saving the DateTime in the database as UTC.

```
from DateTime import DateTime

# inside a class of my entity
self.start_date = datetime.utcnow()
```

This is working fine, the problem is when I try to convert the date back.

**For example.**

> If my application is running in a country with GMT -1, when the user
>   asks to save the entity and it's 2016-07-13 15:00:00, in the database
>   (using the UTC now()) the DateTime will become 2016-07-13 16:00:00.

But when I try to get back the value I have two scenarios:

1. If I don't do anything, I'll receive the DateTime like it's on the database, "2016-07-13 14:00:00"
2. If I try to convert to the local timezone, I'm getting like 2016-07-13 17:00:00. The time was increased by 1 and not decrease was I expected.

I'm trying to use the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library to work with dates, but nothing seems to work.

I'm wondering if what I supposed to do is get the GMT, like (-01:00) then do some math with the DateTime that comes from the database, like sub or sum the GMT hours difference.

Comment: usually you use `timestamp with timezone` in database and value assign with `now()` and then you `select timestamp_column at time zone 'your_zone'`

Comment: Yeap, I'm using `**timestamp** in the database`. I'm using `utcnow()` to avoid any database wrong timezone issue. What I need now is convert this value after receive it from the database. Do `select timestamp_column at time zone 'your_zone'` is not an option in my case.

Comment: `timestamp with timezone` is different from just `timestamp` exactly by saving timezone as well

Comment: Now I understood what you said. But I still can't do this SQL command `select timestamp_column at time zone 'your_zone'` I can only work with the data that comes from the database through an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

My solution for this was, store everything as UTC in my database.

Retrieve the *datetime* as UTC and covert to browsers timezone using *momentjs* library.

Doing like this.

```
moment.tz(moment.utc(datetime), moment.tz.guess());
```